# Получить значение из функции

Tags: c++, списки

Здравствуйте, подскажите , пожалуйста, ошибку. Не могу найти в чем проблема.

Имеется класс `lisdtADT`, который содержит в себе `maxSize`, `size` и `cursor`.
Для утверждения инициализирую `maxSize=11`;` сразу, остальные переменные в конструкторе.

Проблема в том, что метод `DataType getCursor();` *`typedef int DataType;` возвращает неверное значение(мусор).

После дебаггинга, я понял, что `newDataItem` в методе `insert` инициализируется правильными введенными значениями.

Далее, в файле `source.cpp` я пытаюсь подсчитать сумму моих введенных значений строкой `total += samples.getCursor();`. И именно `getCursor();` возвращает мне мусор, который конечно же неправильно считает сумму.

Я думаю, что я выхожу в каком-то месте прибавляю лишнюю еденицу и поэтому происходит такая ошибка.

Помогите,пожалуйста, разобраться.Спасибо.

Мой код:

**ListADT.h**

```
#include<iostream>

const int defMaxListSize = 10;
typedef int DataType;

class ListADT
{
private:
    //Data members
    int maxSize=11;
    int size;
    int cursor;

    DataType *dataItems=NULL;
public:
    //Constructor
    ListADT(int maxNumber = defMaxListSize);

    //Destructor
    ~ListADT();

    //List manipulation operations
    void insert(const DataType &newDataItem);   //Insert after cursor
    void remove();                              //Remove Data item
    //void replace(const DataType &newDataItem);    //Replace data item


    //List status operations 
    bool isEmpty()const;                        //List is empty
    bool isFull() const;                        //List is full

    //List iteration operations
    void gotoBeginning() ;  //Go to beginning
    void gotoEnd();         //Go to end
    bool gotoNext();        //Go to next data item
    bool gotoPrior();       //Go to prior data item
    DataType getCursor();   //Return data item

    //Output the list structure -used in testinf/debugging
    //void showStructure()const;
};
```

**ListADT.cpp**

```
#include "ListADT.h"

ListADT::ListADT(int maxNumber):cursor(0),size(0)
{
    if (maxNumber <= defMaxListSize)
        dataItems = new DataType[maxNumber];
    else
        std::cout << "The list is overloaded" << std::endl;
}

ListADT::~ListADT()
{
    delete dataItems;
}

void ListADT::insert(const DataType & newDataItem)
{
    if (size + 1 <= maxSize) 
    {

        dataItems[cursor] = newDataItem;
        size++;
        cursor++;
    }

}

void ListADT::remove()
{
    if (size - 1 >= 0)
        cursor--;
}

bool ListADT::isEmpty() const
{
    if (size <= 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool ListADT::isFull() const
{
    if (size == defMaxListSize)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void ListADT::gotoBeginning()
{
    cursor = 0;
}

void ListADT::gotoEnd()
{
    cursor = size;
}

bool ListADT::gotoNext()
{
    if (cursor < size)
    {
        cursor++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool ListADT::gotoPrior()
{
    if (!isEmpty() && cursor != 1)
    {
        cursor--;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

DataType ListADT::getCursor()
{
    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        //std::cout << "C: " << cursor << std::endl; //правильный результат
        //cursor--;
        return dataItems[cursor]; // возвращает мусор
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Empty list" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ListADT.h"

void main()
{
    ListADT samples;
    int newSample=0;
    int total = 0;

    //Read in a set of samples from the keyboard.
    std::cout << "Enter list of samples (end with eof): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> newSample;
        samples.insert(newSample);
    }
    //Sum the samples and output the result.

        if (!samples.isEmpty())
        {
            samples.gotoBeginning();

            do {
                std::cout << "CUR " << samples.getCursor() << std::endl;
                total += samples.getCursor();
            }
            while (samples.gotoNext());
        }
        std::cout << "Sum is " << total << std::endl;
        system("pause");
}
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В insert вы делаете size++ и cursor++, хотя по значению в cursor после увеличения ничего нет. И соответственно проверка в в gotoNext будет успешна, хотя в массиве по этому значению cursor ничего нет.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Да-да, я понял вас, вот он лишний ++ , но только не пойму ,как я могу исправить это.

Comment: Удалите оттуда cursor++, это у вас делается в getNext

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Тогда значения даже в `Cur` получается мусор. Не понимаю, где то рядом... ответ.

Comment: Массив по индексам 0-9, в getCursor cursor 9, size 10 сейчас у вас будет принят и ++ будет сделано. Делайте проверку на < size - 1

Comment: @DanielProtopopov разобрался! Спасибо! Напишу ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была найдена в методе `bool ListADT::gotoNext()`. Происходил лишний шаг на единицу и поэтому десятый элемент возвращал мусор.

1. Метод `insert()` остается без изменений:

   ```
    void ListADT::insert(const DataType & newDataItem)
   {
      if (size + 1 <= maxSize) 
     {

       dataItems[cursor] = newDataItem;
       size++;
       cursor++;
     }

   }
   ```
2. Метод `bool ListADT::gotoNext()`. Меняем в условии `size` на `size-1`

   ```
    bool ListADT::gotoNext()
    {
          if (cursor < size-1)
         {
            cursor++;
          return true;
         }
        return false;
    }
   ```

Comment: Вам в insert всё-таки не нужно делать cursor++, достаточно иметь dataItems[size] = newDataItem; size++. Иначе если будет вставка посередине использования курсора будет бо-бо